# access to struct fields based on struct name

Tags: matlab, struct

I have problem to access each field of struct in MATLAB. I tried to convert it to Cell however, it give me error :( 
How can I access each field with 2 loops ?
I have wrote following code :

```
a=load(goalMFile);
struct_name=fieldnames(a);
struct_cell=struct2cell(a);
cellsz = cellfun(@size,struct_cell,'uni',false);
ans=cellsz{:};
row=ans(1);
col=ans(2);
for counter1=1:row
for counter2=1:col
a.struct_name{(counter1-1)*counter2+counter2} % the error is Here
end

end
```

I will really appreciate, If anyone could help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can access a structure dynamically with `s.(fname)` where `fname` is char variable. Note the `( )` around `fname`.

An example will clarify:

```
% Example structure
s.A = 10;
s.B = 20;

% Retrieve fieldnames
fnames = fieldnames(s);

% Loop with numeric index
for ii = 1:numel(fnames)
    s.(fnames{ii})
end

% ...or loop by fieldname directly
for f = fnames'
    s.(f{:})
end
```

Comment: +1 Your answer helped me a lot. I just want to add that this can be easily combined with a sort operation on the field names (which are Strings in my case): for tempFieldname = sort(fieldnames(s))' ...